# How to use URL structure to call PHP code

Tags: url-rewriting

I want to use this:

```
http://www.example.com/directory/alan-walker
```

instead of calling `alan-walker.php` (which is non-existent) it should call `directory.php?s=alan-walker`

Is this possible?

I suspect it's the `.htaccess` rewrite no?

Effectively what this does is it means I can use this:

```
/directory/alan-walker (good)
```

instead of

```
directory?s=alan-walker (bad)
```

Comment: You can't do that with rewrite rules, but does it have to be a completely separate file? Could you not include the file from within WP? What does `directory.php` do? And if it does what I think it does, how do you prevent directory traversal attacks?

Comment: When you ask about `.htaccess` you ask in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `alan-walker` is just an example and this could be any string of this form. (Or is it literally just "alan-walker", as in you example?)

You can do this with a single `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` *before* the WordPress front-controller. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/([a-z-]+)$ /directory.php?s=$1 [L]
```

This will rewrite `/directory/<something>` to `/directory.php?s=<something>`,
 where `<something>` consists of one or more of the characters `a` to `z` and `-`.

---

> ...instead of calling alan-walker.php

This would only happen if you have MultiViews enabled. And only if `alan-walker.php` existed as a real file (which you say it doesn't). It is not enabled by default, however, if it is, it can be disabled by calling the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Change the Search-URL of WordPress - Add code in function.php and customize with directory**

```
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

**Yes, it is also possible via htacces rules, but the source is an example for custom solutions on an redirect.**

```
# search redirect
# this will take anything in the query string, minus any extraneous values, and turn them into a clean working url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [NC,R,L]
```

[image]